# Can SAP BO Object Application be recorded using Web Performance Test (VS 2012)?

Tags: load-testing, business-objects

I tried recording using BI Launch Pad but I am getting

> "An error occurred while retrieving the document from the storage token. (Error: RWI 00313) (Error: INF )",_ERR_REPORT, okCB

My SAP BO Object application version is of 4.1 version and this above error was fixed in version 4.1 still I am getting this same error?

After increasing STACK_SIZE limit and Maximum Document Per User limit in SAP BI Application I am in doubt whether Visual Studio Support web testing of SAP BO Objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to set the values

```
WID_FAIappLOVER_SIZE = 20
WID_STORAGE_TOKEN_STACK_SIZE = 0
```

In "webi.properties" file at your WebAppServer?

Comment: This is resolved problem was with dynamic string variable extraction and passing them to later requests.